# How to computers download files from the internet without port forwarding being set in the router?

Tags: networking, nat, ipv4

Because of NAT, we know that a computer in public network cannot access a computer inside a local area network (LAN) without setting port forwarding in the router.

So, how does a computer inside a LAN actually download files from the internet? I guess the server on the internet only know to send files to the public IP address of my ISP's router, and how does the file actually get to my computer, with potentially several layers of NAT in between? Is there a temporary port-forwarding automatically being set in the router?

I am not a computer network expert, so if I get any concept wrong, please point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fundamental part of what NAT is and how it works--no port forwarding necessary. When a network request passes through a layer of NAT, the router performing the translation keeps track of where the request came from (w/o passing through additional NAT layers). When a response arrives, the router forwards it back to the origin of its associated request.

Similarly, this is also the reason why, as you mentioned, public-to-local requests require port-forwarding. When a router receives something without an associated request, it doesn't know which local device to forward things on to.

From a technical standpoint, there's no port forwarding involved. From a logical perspective, however, this can be considered a form of temporary port-forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

This is called connection tracking or stateful connection tracking.  It will keep track of the source address+port from behind NAT and destination address+port from the WAN of a connection to know where to send packets back. So yes, this is a kind of express port forward.

https://www.rigacci.org/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php/doc/appunti/linux/sa/iptables/conntrack.html
http://www.fibrevillage.com/sysadmin/199-linux-iptables-connection-tracking-configuration